# String not contain not working properly in java

Tags: java, string, contains

I want to check bracket part of below string. If bracket part contains in a string then "Contain" should print. But in my case it's printing "Not Contain".

```
String synonym = "security (generic term)"

synonym = synonym.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");

if ((!synonym.contains("generic term")) || (!synonym.contains("similar term"))
    (!synonym.contains("related term")) || (!synonym.contains("antonym"))) {
    System.out.println("Not Contain);
} else {
    System.out.println("Contain);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((!synonym.contains("generic term")) || (!synonym.contains("similar term"))
(!synonym.contains("related term")) || (!synonym.contains("antonym")))
```

Will be true unless `synonym` contains *all* of these terms. (Because the `||` condition. I.e. even if it does contain one, it will not contain one of the other ones, making one of the conditions evaluate to true.)

To fix this use `&&`:

```
if ((!synonym.contains("generic term")) && (!synonym.contains("similar term"))
(!synonym.contains("related term")) && (!synonym.contains("antonym")))
```

Comment: Why we are not using OR operator here?

Comment: Because the `||` operator makes it so that if any of the conditions evaluate to `true` the `if` statement will become true @ManishVerma